# Can I use Javascript to draw in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: node.js, adobe-illustrator

I have a client that wants to script commands to Adobe Illustrator. I'm sure it's easy, but am a basic when it comes to js
I am using access points on an excel spreadsheet, with deminsions and descriptions. Can provide samples and more details at requests.
Bob

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Bob. Folks here are happy to help, but need the details up-front. Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your post with more details. Also, consider adding a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the current state of your progress, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions

Comment: Yes you can use JS: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use js to draw in Adobe Illustrator.

The VBA is more preferable if you intend to draw from the MS Excel app, however.

The Code below is written in VBA to draw a Lemniscate.  You can use it as an example:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private ai_Doc As Illustrator.Document

Private Function Get_Lemniscate(ByVal Point_Count As Long) As Variant
Const PI As Double = 3.14159265358979
Dim t As Double
Dim t3 As Double
Dim t4 As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim ret As Variant

    ReDim ret(Point_Count)
    For i = LBound(ret) To UBound(ret)
        t = Math.Tan(PI * ((i / Point_Count) - 0.5))
        t3 = t * t * t
        t4 = t * t3
        ret(i) = Array( _
            500 + 300 * (t + t3) / (1 + t4), _
            300 + 300 * (t - t3) / (1 + t4))
    Next
    Get_Lemniscate = ret
End Function

Private Function Get_AI_Document() As Illustrator.Document
    With New Illustrator.Application
        ' It may be necessary to make AI visible here - it is a small trick 
        If (.Documents.Count = 0) Then
            .Documents.Add
        End If
        Set Get_AI_Document = .ActiveDocument
    End With
End Function

Private Sub Draw_AI_Path(ByRef Point_Array As Variant)
Dim New_Path As Illustrator.PathItem
    Set New_Path = ai_Doc.PathItems.Add
    New_Path.SetEntirePath Point_Array
    ' Do some other stuff (colors, line stroke etc)
End Sub


Sub Test()
    Set ai_Doc = Get_AI_Document
    Draw_AI_Path Get_Lemniscate(6000)
End Sub
```